# How Do I Set up my homepage?

Tags: php, web

So I have developed a website with the main page named as home.php. I have also got a domain name and hosting from Godaddy. What I want to know is that how do i tell my site to display the home.php as the homepage?

I want that when the user goes to example.com -- home.php should be presented, and not example.com/home.php.

thanks.

Comment: Where do wish this to be presented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name the file index.php and it will work

Answer (score 3):

just rename your `home.php` to `index.php`

Answer (score 1):

You're options:

- Rename you're file to `index.php`
- Rename you're file to `default.php`
- Do a [iFrame](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)
- Do a php redirect: `header("Location: home.php");`
- You could do a .htaccess redirect: `DirectoryIndex home.php`

**I would choose #1 or #2**!

If you choose to do an iFrame you would have to "break out" to enable the back button in the browser.

If you choose to do a redirect with php you will waste server resources.

.htaccess way: ...Don't know what's bad.

Answer (score 0):

you can:

- rename `home.php` to `index.php`
- create `index.php` with content

```
<?php header('Location: home.php');?>
```

But, I don't recommend option #2 as it generate another useless HTTP request.